# MySQL for Spyder(Python 3.5)

Tags: python, mysql, anaconda, spyder

I'm trying to find out if I can use MySQL via the Spyder IDE (Python 3.5 edition. I've had a look around and know its possible to use Python with MySQL (I've done that already a long time ago now), however, I can't seem to find any solutions to my particular question/problem. The examples I've looked at won't work for Spyder...?  Is there anyone out there who might know?

Many thanks!

Comment: NB/ I used the python mysql connector within linux which works fine. Obviously my problem is with Spyder

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) Could you describe the problems you're seeing?

Comment: I'm pretty new to the Spyder IDE I should mention, but its been great so far. Excuse my ignorance with this, but I typed in import MySQLdb into the IPython console and the console itself. The error I get in both cases is: "No module module named MySQLdb". Usually when importing modules, for example, maths-type problems, its just a case of "from math import*". Am I missing something similar with my current problem?

Comment: It depends on how you're using Spyder. How did you install it and the mysql connector?